# Query Oracle database for a specific Day

Tags: oracle

I need to find all the events that happen on a certain day of the week  - say Wednesday.  I can convert my date field to display the day by using to_char(event_date, 'Day'), but when I put this in a where clause it doesn't return any results.

For example:
where to_char(event_date, 'Day') = 'Wednesday'

I also tried this:
select weekday from
(select to_char(event_date, 'Day') "weekday" from Events)
where weekday = 'Wednesday'

Neither one returns any results.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: wrap your `to_char(...)` function in a `trim()` function to get rid of extra whitespace characters on the ends. That solved it for me.

Comment: Oracle has a format mask which will get rid of spaces. Instead of `rtrim()` you can use `to_char(event_date, 'fmDay')`. Not sure this will solve the problem if it's not working for "Wednesday", which wouldn't have any whitespace around it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your database language is not english, i suggest you set `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` like this:

```
to_char(event_date, 'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

Check for example

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') from dual; --returns Tuesday
select to_char(sysdate, 'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=SPANISH') from dual; --returns Martes
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't good approach anyway. Just for example, to_char(event_date, 'Day') with my NLS settings will produce 'Среда', not 'Wednesday'. Try to use

```
where to_char(event_day, 'D') = '3'
```

It should work, just for example

```
SQL> select dt, to_char(dt, 'D')
  2  from (select trunc(sysdate, 'MM') + rownum - 1 dt from dual connect by level <= 31)
  3  where to_char(dt, 'D') = '3';

DT          TO_CHAR(DT,'D')
----------- ---------------
03.12.2014  3
10.12.2014  3
17.12.2014  3
24.12.2014  3
31.12.2014  3
```